# What does Sin[2. x] mean?

Tags: code-request, expression-form

I am working with a particularly long function that, when I want to evaluate it at a certain $x$, shows:

[image]

> As you can see there are expressions herein of the form Sin[2. x] or Cos[2. x]. What do these mean?
> Are they simply Sin[2*x] and Cos[2*x]? Because if so, Mathematica cannot solve it when I want to find the intersection of this function at a certain value.

EDIT: My aim is to find the value of x between $0$ and $2\pi$ for which this function equals $2\pi/10$. But when I compute   `Reduce[%26 == 2 \[Pi]/10 && 0 < x < 2 \[Pi], x, Reals]`
the code is running without end.
EDIT 2: My code is

```
f[x_] := ArcCos[
   0.5` (-0.0043381411060778655` + 1.6135846934935796` Cos[2.` x] + 
      1.1688197403120535` Sin[
        2.` x])] (-((0.09395454520105649` (0.07361686700773626` Cos[
             2.` x] - 
           0.10162991408317741` Sin[2.` x]))/(\[Sqrt](Abs[
            0.07361686700773626` Cos[2.` x] - 
             0.10162991408317741` Sin[2.` x]]^2 + 
           Abs[0.09304548749885659` + 
             0.03408709778405973` Cos[2.` x] + 
             0.02469140475898721` Sin[2.` x]]^2 + 
           Abs[-1.1667561291381148` Cos[2.` x] + 
             1.61073582699283` Sin[
               2.` x]]^2))) + (0.9955764879887747` \
(-1.1667561291381148` Cos[2.` x] + 
         1.61073582699283` Sin[2.` x]))/(\[Sqrt](Abs[
          0.07361686700773626` Cos[2.` x] - 
           0.10162991408317741` Sin[2.` x]]^2 + 
         Abs[0.09304548749885659` + 0.03408709778405973` Cos[2.` x] + 
           0.02469140475898721` Sin[2.` x]]^2 + 
         Abs[-1.1667561291381148` Cos[2.` x] + 
           1.61073582699283` Sin[2.` x]]^2)))

NMinimize[(f[x] - 2 \[Pi]/10)^2 && 0 < x < 2 \[Pi],  x \[Element] Reals]
```

Comment: It's just shorthand for Sin[2.0 * x] but the 2 is numeric instead of exact. To solve your problem you'll probably need to use exact values, or failing that use NSolve or even use minimization to a target value e.g something like `NMinimize[(function - target)^2, variables]`.

Comment: @flinty Thank you for your suggestion. NSolve does also not work, and if I try ```NMinimize[(%26 - 2 \[Pi]/10)^2 && 0 < x < 2 \[Pi], x, Reals]```, I get: "Options expected (instead of \!\(\*TemplateBox[{},\"Reals\"]\)) \
beyond position 2 in \
\!\(NMinimize[\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-\*FractionBox[\(\[Pi]\), \
\(5\)]\) + ArcCos[0.5`\\\ Plus[<<3>>]]\\\ \
\((\(-0.09395454520105649`\)\\\ Power[<<2>>]\\\ Plus[<<2>>] + \
0.9955764879887747`\\\ Power[<<2>>]\\\ Plus[<<2>>])\))\), \(2\)] && 0 \
< x < 2\\\ \[Pi], x, \*TemplateBox[{},\"Reals\"]]\). An option must \
be a rule or a list of rules."

Comment: @MichaelHenchard, the syntax for defining domain in ``NMinimize`` is a bit different, try: ``NMinimize[(%26 - 2 \[Pi]/10)^2 && 0 < x < 2 \[Pi], x \[Element] Reals]``.

Comment: @Domen Thank you for your comment. Now however it says "NMinimize: The function value False is not a number at {x} = {-0.829053}."

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include a copy-paste Mathematica code (not a screenshot) – it will be easier to help and diagnose your problem :-)

Comment: @Domen Will do, thank you!

Comment: @Domen I have added my code.

Comment: `NMinimize[{(f[x] - 2 \[Pi]/10)^2, 0 < x < 2 \[Pi]}, x]`

Comment: @cvgmt That does the trick, thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) and simplify your function

```
f[x_] = ArcCos[
     0.5` (-0.0043381411060778655` + 1.6135846934935796` Cos[2.` x] + 
        1.1688197403120535` Sin[
          2.` x])] (-((0.09395454520105649` (0.07361686700773626` Cos[
               2.` x] - 
             0.10162991408317741` Sin[2.` x]))/(√(Abs[
               0.07361686700773626` Cos[2.` x] - 
                0.10162991408317741` Sin[2.` x]]^2 + 
             Abs[
               0.09304548749885659` + 0.03408709778405973` Cos[2.` x] + 
                0.02469140475898721` Sin[2.` x]]^2 + 
             Abs[-1.1667561291381148` Cos[2.` x] + 
                1.61073582699283` Sin[
                  2.` x]]^2))) + (0.9955764879887747` (-1.1667561291381148` \
Cos[2.` x] + 
           1.61073582699283` Sin[2.` x]))/(√(Abs[
             0.07361686700773626` Cos[2.` x] - 
              0.10162991408317741` Sin[2.` x]]^2 + 
           Abs[
             0.09304548749885659` + 0.03408709778405973` Cos[2.` x] + 
              0.02469140475898721` Sin[2.` x]]^2 + 
           Abs[-1.1667561291381148` Cos[2.` x] + 
              1.61073582699283` Sin[2.` x]]^2))) // Rationalize[#, 0] & // 
  FullSimplify

(* (ArcCos[-(11764235/5423629482) + (30306263 Cos[2 x])/37563895 + (
     27078224 Sin[2 x])/
     46334303] (-12317327964773499476837597655773578855689996103168 Cos[
       2 x] + 
     17004377307481709353660395259265893865864856810155 Sin[
       2 x]))/(10541040306010238271605865288500484395709068414280 \
√(Abs[(18359552 Cos[2 x])/249393281 - (19606853 Cos[x] Sin[x])/
        96462017]^2 + 
      Abs[(73214772 Cos[2 x])/62750707 - (75644170 Sin[2 x])/46962493]^2 + 
      Abs[
       9582991/102992539 + (5783815 Cos[2 x])/169677543 + (11995181 Sin[2 x])/
        485803911]^2)) *)
```

If you plot the function you will see that there are multiple values of `x` that satisfy the equation `f[x] == 2Pi/10`

```
Plot[{f[x], 2 Pi/10}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Use [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) with different initial values to find all solutions

```
sol = N[FindRoot[f[x] == 2 Pi/10, {x, #}, WorkingPrecision -> 50] & /@ {0.6, 
    1.9, 3.8, 5}, 15]

(* {{x -> 0.625169188406799}, {x -> 1.88157999720400}, {x -> 
   3.76676184199659}, {x -> 5.02317265079380}} *)

f[x] == 2 Pi/10 /. sol

(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```